# SP13: Move Count Total to Column

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, custom-list, calculated-column

I am sure this is possible, but cannot spin my head around the idea on getting it done.  I have a custom list view that has totaling on a column.

Intent: I want the total number from the column to appear in its on column.

I thought if I a calculated column to pull it into another column this would work.  But the total is not its own column.  It is the Item Total view feature of SharePoint.

Can this be done?

[image]

Comment: Do you need it to be an empty column, with only a header that displays the count? Also, if you don't need the total of items in SharePoint, what total do you need?

Comment: do you need this to just display in list view ? or you want count to be updated in each items ?

Comment: Did you add the calculated formula to the separate column already?

Comment: @MohamedDerhalli Yes, the column should be empty with only header that displays the count.  This is all in the same list.  It would be the column next to the column that has the count

Comment: @SiddharthVaghasia As the count increases or decreases that number should be reflected in the Total column.

Comment: @FlatBanana Not yet.  I am trying to decide which formula to use.  I guess I would use the formula to display the same text in the Total column. Not sure.

Comment: So basically, you need to display the count of items in the list, but in a separate column, and the column values for all items will be empty?

Comment: That isn't how calculated columns work, they can only go "horizontal" (the properties of the current item), they have no knowledge of "vertical" items (above or below them). You'll have to do some sort of JSLink/CSR customization for this.

Comment: @MohamedDerhalli Exactly.

Comment: @Eric Alexander this is great point.  If I make each line item it's own total (i.e. 1) and total them with a calculated column..maybe?

Comment: @SharePointLady, that won't work, you will need to do as Eric said, or you would just add a content editor webpart on the page, where you'll get the total # of items in the list with JS and update a value in the content editor webpart but it won't be disaplayed as a column

Answer (score 2):

This can be done if you need a column to display the total with no values inside for each item.

Create a column, call it anything, for example Items Count, make it of type Single line of text, and for the default value, make it calculated, and type the default value as `=" "` , click OK.

Go to advanced settings, allow management of content types, and hide this column so you won't be able to fill it

Note that this will work for upcoming items as the value will be calculated when you add an item, not for the previously added ones.